# What is the overhead associated with instantiating a Web Reference proxy class?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering what the overhead associated with instantiating a Web Reference (one generated by wsdl.exe) proxy class is? Is the overhead substantial enough where I would want to consider using a singleton instance for my application?

In my MVC app for instance, I will likely have some cases where a controller and repository class both need an instance of the web reference proxy class. Currently, I have my IoC container (StructureMap) set to automatically inject a new instance of the proxy each time it is used in a constructor, but if that could have significant performance implications I can easily modify the configuration to use a singleton instance instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the overhead of instantiating an object is about .00006 seconds.

The proxy won't do any performance degrading work until you start making calls with it.

Comment: Agreed - the noticeably / measurable performance hit comes when you actually make a service call.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't any kind of communication going on behind the scenes during instantiation. Once you start making calls though, is there going to be a performance difference between making 2 calls from a single proxy instance, vs making 1 call from 2 different proxy instances?